# MediaPlayer plays the same file twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

So, I am trying to load/stream a mp3 file from a link online. The problem I am having with the implementation is that the same audio file is being played twice.

The code is as follows:

**Initial Declaration:**

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

**(in fragment) OnCreateView:**

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
playPodCast(getPosition);
```

**PlayPodcast method:**

```
public void playPodCast(int index) {
        try {
            String url = toGet.get(index).get("URL").toString();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Also I have implemented a play/pause button:

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                // Changing button image to play button
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
        } else {
            // Resume song
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                // Changing button image to pause button
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The strange thing about the implementation is that in the dual playing mode of the audio file, only one of them is accessible through this play/pause implementation.

For e.g., If audio file A(1st) is played at first, after a few seconds the file A(2nd) will be played again. Out of these two A(1st) is controllable through the play/pause implementation.

Help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like there are two instances of MediaPlayer being created. Without seeing more code, it is hard to say what's going on for sure. Are you releasing the player anywhere? Have you tried putting logcat outputs in the onCreateView?

The most sure fire way to prevent this problem is to host the MediaPlayer in a local Service. As Fragments are somewhat volatile, it's maybe not the best idea to have the lifespan of a MediaPlayer tied to one.

Comment: what if i used the mediaPlayer in a service ? would that help  I noticed in my log that the onResume is called twice thats why the mediaPlayer is playing twice.

Comment: Yes, putting it in a Service will help. I'm not sure under what circumstances onResume would get called twice, but if there's only one MediaPlayer it's not possible for it to play twice.

Comment: I am actually using a viewPager ... so does that change things ?? I am also very confused at why the mediaPlayer is being called twice. On viewing the log I thought the onResume being called twice would be a logical explanation. Thanks for your help :) I will try to implement the mediaPlayer on a Service then.